# Calling methods from controllers to mongoose schema file (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Hey guys i am pretty new to Nodejs so let me first describe my problem 
I created a mongooseschema of comments like

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const commentsschema = new Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  middlename:{
    type:String
  },
  lastname:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  comments:{
      type:String,
      required:true
  },
  upvote:{
      type:Number
  },
  downvote:{
      type:Number
  }

}); 
module.exports = mongoose.model("comments", commentsschema);
```

then in my controllers file i created it and added it to db whenever user submits a comment

```
exports.postcomment = (req, res, next) => {

  //All firstname, lastname etc are taken from req.body just to make my code short i havent included those lines

  const commentinpage = new Comments({
    firstname: fname,
    middlename:mname,
    lastname:lname,
    comments: comment,
    upvote: 0,
    downvote: 0
  });
  return commentinpage.save().then(() => {
    res.redirect("/");
  });
};
```

now in later point of time when another user clicks on upvote button i want to increase the upvote entry in my db so i want to call a method in mongoose schema ..So i tried like this

```
 const Comments = require("../modals/Comments");
 Comments.upvoteco().then(result=>{
 console.log(this.upvote)
 }
```

and then in my schema

```
commentsschema.methods.upvoteco=function(){
  console.log(this.upvote)
return  ++this.upvote

}
```

but i get the error `TypeError: Comments.upvoteco is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not call the method defined in schema with the model, You can call it with the object instance i.e using and mongoose object instance(document) in that specific collection.

And to call one with the model you should define a static method:

try changing:

```
commentsschema.methods.upvoteco = function() {
  console.log(this.upvote);
  return ++this.upvote;
}
```

to this:

```
commentsschema.statics.upvoteco = function() {
  console.log(this.upvote);
  return ++this.upvote;
}
```

and try calling your method like:

```
Comments.upvoteco(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    } else {
        console.log(this.upvote);
    }
});
```

Check the official docs for more clearity: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html

hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for d help but still got the same error :(

Comment: Can you update the question with whatever you just tried

Comment: just replaced methods with statics thts all

Comment: Where are you calling the method?? Can you try printing you model just to check if you are getting it or not?

Comment: sorry didnt understood what u meant by sayin "where are you calling your method" ?

Comment: i meant in which file you are calling it? Are you sure your model is imported properly?

Comment: and one more thing if i remove then block from  Comments.upvoteco().then(result=>{
 console.log(this.upvote)
 } its working but then console .log(this.upvote) gives undefine

Comment: and console.log(this) gives me Model {comments}

Comment: I've updated the answer, seems like mongoose methods doesn't yet support promises or you need to explicitly return a promise from the static methods, so i just changed it with callback. Hope this works :)

Comment: Good read: https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-add-static-methods-with-mongoose-237

Comment: ahh dude thanks for effort and help but i m stressed now in my commentsschema.statics.upvoteco if i console.log(this.firsname) its giving me undefined :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197098/discussion-between-mohammed-amir-ansari-and-ratnabh-kumar-rai).